# Slot assignment in JST SM connectors

Tags: connector, polarity

I am using **JST SM** connectors for connecting two sets of wire. There are two slots in 2-pin connector. I wish to know, what is general convention for assigning the polarity to these slots? Is it *slot 1-ground & slot 2-Vcc* or *slot 1-Vcc & slot 2-ground*? Also how should I assign these slots for control pins(like clk/sw/sck)? Is there any uniform convention? And what is general assignment of slots in case of 3-pin connector? I have attached an image of the connector with visible slot numbers. Any Help is appreciated.

[image: Image attached - JST SM2.5 connector(Male & Female with slot numbers)]

Comment: As long as you don't follow a standard, I don't think there is a convention.

Comment: I like to put ground at pin 1, but that’s just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the standard has already been set by the battery manufacturers?  I have many toy 4.8v NiCd battery packs wired with pin 1 Vcc and Pin 2 ground.  Using these as stand-alone plugs and sockets there is no problem, but wishing to use one of these pre-wired battery packs, it becomes important.

[image]

Comment: If these connectors are already often used for battery packs, the OP may want to consider using something else to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your comment duskwuff... however, one can purchase these connectors already wired (as in the top example) both ways.  If the battery manufacturers have chosen a polarity, surely the standard has been set by them?  I like this connector for low current applications as they lock shut.  I could change the female plug on the battery, but that would render the supplied chargers incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The OP didn't mention a battery anywhere -- they mentioned that the connector might be used for _power_, but that could just as easily be 12V as it could 3.7V or 4.8V…

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time looking too (in my case for a JST XH 2-pin battery connector polarity standard). Did not find any standards/conventions.

- Batteries from different manufacturers (in my case 1-cell LiPo batteries) use different polarity.
- Connectors sold separately (with attached wires in the male connector) also use different polarity depending on the manufacturer.

If you are making a PCB, try to indicate in the silkscreen of your board the connector polarity (i.e.: where "+" and "-" go) to make it clear for anybody (and for you when you forget in in the future).